# Get the top 2 values for each unique value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, pandas-loc

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
student       marks     term
steve         55        1
jordan        66        2
steve         53        1
alan          74        2
jordan        99        1
steve         81        2
alan          78        1
alan          76        2
jordan        48        1
```

I would like to return highest two scores for each student

```
student  marks    term
steve      81     2
steve      55     1
jordan     99     1
jordan     66     2
alan       78     1
alan       76     2
```

I have tried

```
df = df.groupby('student')['marks'].max()
```

but it returns 1 row, I would like each student in the order they are mentioned with top two scores.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `groupby` + `nlargest` to find the 2 largest values; then use `loc` to sort in the order they appear in `df`:

```
out = (df.groupby('student')['marks'].nlargest(2)
       .droplevel(1)
       .loc[df['student'].drop_duplicates()]
       .reset_index())
```

Output:

```
  student  marks
0   steve     81
1   steve     55
2  jordan     99
3  jordan     66
4    alan     78
5    alan     76
```

If you want to keep "terms" as well, you could use the index:

```
idx = df.groupby('student')['marks'].nlargest(2).index.get_level_values(1)
out = df.loc[idx].set_index('student').loc[df['student'].drop_duplicates()].reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  student  marks  term
0   steve     81     2
1   steve     55     1
2  jordan     99     1
3  jordan     66     2
4    alan     78     1
5    alan     76     2
```

@sammywemmy suggested a better way to derive the second result:

```
out = (df.loc[df.groupby('student', sort=False)['marks'].nlargest(2)
              .index.get_level_values(1)]
       .reset_index(drop=True))
```

Comment: How can I keep the term column too?

Comment: ``df.loc[df.groupby('student', sort = False).marks.nlargest(2).index.get_level_values(-1)]`` might allow you avoid setting index and dropping duplicates

Comment: @sammywemmy that looks very neat. I put it in. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
df = df.groupby(['student', 'term'])['marks'].max()
```

(with an optional `.reset_index()` )

Answer (score 0):

Sorting before grouping should suffice, since you need to keep the `term` column:

```py
df.sort_values('marks').groupby('student', sort = False).tail(2)
  student  marks  term
0   steve     55     1
1  jordan     66     2
7    alan     76     2
6    alan     78     1
5   steve     81     2
4  jordan     99     1
```